# OfficeJS: Maximum Range Call Stack Size Error

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

I'm using OfficeJS in a Word add-in and seeing some strange behavior regarding an error that shows up in the console with the log "Maximum Range Call Stack Size Error".

The code below works for almost all documents. But for specific documents, it looks like the `file.getSliceAsync` fails and causes the error. However, when testing, some of our developers can reproduce the error and some cannot. It either works 100% of the time or 0% of the time for a single developer.

We have tried clearing caches, but without success. There's nothing that sticks out in the documents that fail here.

It seems like this is a bug in the OfficeJS library, but I'm not sure if there is any workaround.

Any ideas?

Code below:

```
static async getFileContent(): Promise<number[]> {
    console.log('Starting file content retrieval');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return Office.context.document.getFileAsync(
        Office.FileType.Compressed,
        async (result) => {
          if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            const file: Office.File = result.value;
            console.log('Slice count: ' + file.sliceCount);

            // Get all file slices
            const fileSlicePromises: Promise<number[]>[] = [
              ...Array(file.sliceCount).keys(),
            ].map((counter) => WordDocumentService.getFileSlice(file, counter));
            console.log('fileSlices length: ' + fileSlicePromises.length);
            // Combine file slices into a single file and then close the file
            const dataSlices: number[][] = await Promise.all(fileSlicePromises).finally(
              () => WordDocumentService.closeOfficeFile(file)
            );
            console.log('Concatenating data');
            return resolve([].concat(...dataSlices));
          } else {
            return reject(`Failed to get file content: ${result?.error?.message}`);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }

  static getFileSlice(file: Office.File, sliceIndex: number): Promise<number[]> {
    console.log('Getting file slice: ' + sliceIndex);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return file.getSliceAsync(sliceIndex, (result) => {
        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
          return resolve(result.value.data);
        } else {
          return reject(
            `Failed to get file slice ${sliceIndex} from file: ${result?.error?.message}`
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }

  static closeOfficeFile(file: Office.File): Promise<void> {
    console.log('Closing office file');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return file.closeAsync((result) => {
        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
          return resolve();
        } else {
          return reject(`Failed to close file: ${result?.error?.message}`);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: For the devs that are getting the error, do they all get it on exactly the same documents? Is there a difference in RAM size or drive type (SSD vs. HD) on the machines where it happens? If you copy the contents of a doc where it fails into a new doc, does the code fail in the same way on the new doc?

Comment: Good questions: Yes, the devs get the same error on the same doc. There isn't a substantial difference in RAM size. Our dev machines are reasonably powerful, they either have 16 GB or 32 GB or RAM and the file is only a couple hundred KB. All have SSD drives. 

Good question about the content copying - maybe its metadata about the document, maybe its content. I'll try and take a look.

Comment: Copying content over to another document still produces the error, so its not an issue with the metadata, but instead the content itself. I would post the content here but unfortunately its confidential for my company :(

Comment: My next step would be to copy a small bit of failing doc into a new one, maybe just the headers/footers, or just the section breaks (if any), or the first couple of words. See if the new doc is broken. If not, copy more into the new doc, a little at a time, testing after each addition, until it breaks.

Comment: Another thing to check: Using this article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins, see if embedded webview control being used differs in the machines where it's broken from those where it always works.